# JButton added but not showing up at runtime

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton

I'm using a book to learn java. I'm have made a Swing window but when I try to make JButtons, they are not visible at runtime. I've copied the code exactly as it is, but it is still not visible. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
class Buttons extends JFrame
{
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    public Buttons()
    {
        super("Swing Window");
        setSize(500,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(pnl);
        setVisible(true);
        pnl.add(new JButton("Click Me"));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Window gui = new Window();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm using a book to learn java."*  If that code above is a result, I don't think it is a very good book..  BTW - The `main(String[])` method usually creates an instance of the class it is in.  This one I would have expected to be more like `Buttons gui = new Buttons(); gui.setVisible(true);`..

Comment: The book actually makes us learn Java using, sort of, puzzles. Like: 'class HelloWorld{public static void main(String[] args){}}' Then it tells us to insert this code in between the main method brackets: 'System.out.println("Hi")'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
    setVisible(true);
    pnl.add(new JButton("Click Me"));
```

To:

```
    pnl.add(new JButton("Click Me"));
    pack(); // very important!
    setVisible(true); // should be last!
```

Comment: Thank you but a bit complicated for me (12 year old).

Answer (score -1):

Change Window to Buttons and it works fine!!!

```
import javax.swing.*;    

class Buttons extends JFrame
{
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
public Buttons()
 {
    super("Swing Window");
    setSize(500,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(pnl);
    setVisible(true);
    pnl.add(new JButton("Click Me"));
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Buttons gui = new Buttons();
}
```

}